# How to connect TFS through Internet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I am working on a large application in team environment. We use to Team Foundation Server to  control source code with VS2010.We are using LAN to connect TFS which works great in an small office but now we need to connect TFS through Internet.

What actually I want to know that we have many developers they reside in different location worldwide. We want to download there work directly in the TFS server through Internet like LAN. We will have also connect LAN users who work on this application and want to connect both kind of users parallel.

Note: WE DON'T WANT TO USE VPN.

Is there any possibility to do this kind of work in TFS? Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the answer without VPN, that's how you create a Lan/Wan over the net. Have you looked at the TFS proxy to improve performance when you have it up and running?

Comment: Thanks to reply. We want to connect TFS like web addresses and other application which use global IP address for end to end connectivity. I think it is possible but I don't know HOW???

Comment: You might wan to look into the Team Foundation Services as well (reply if you need an invite code). It allows you to run TFS in the Cloud with minimum overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definately expose TFS over the internet.  TFS is basically a set of web services hosted in IIS, just make your server internet-visible and you're set.

There are some security best practices you probably want to consider though:

1) You should configure an SSL cert in IIS and connect to TFS using HTTPS (an option when connecting in VS).

2) You should place your SQL Server database on a separate machine that is not directly exposed to the internet (but is visible to the Application Tier server).  SSRS should reside on the AT server, the DB and SSAS should be on the Data Tier server.

Comment: Links: TFS+SSL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833872.aspx Adding domain names in TFS: http://www.edsquared.com/2011/01/03/Using+Friendly+DNS+Names+In+Your+TFS+Environment.aspx