# Setting up TFS with FTP?

Tags: tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect TFS through Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555349/how-to-connect-tfs-through-internet)

I have a project I've been working on and I'd like to set up source control on it so my friend can join in and work on it with me. I've never done any kind of windows server administration so this is quite confusing for me.

We have a server that hosts our website, can I just create a directory on that server and host the project builds there? If so how can I set this up?

Am I supposed to install an instance of TFS on that server or can I just host the project builds in a directory on that server without installing anything on it?

I'm looking for a simple and secure way to work on the project with my friend. I've worked with TFS before so I know how to connect to the tfs server etc but how to set it up is beyond me. Can anyone advise me please in layman's terms how to make this setup, I'm a total server newb.

Thanks

Comment: I'd really encourage you to consider familiarizing yourself with an open standard like git or Subversion (among many other good choices) instead of MS Team Foundation Server: [Getting Started with Github](http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/getting-started-with-github/). Long term, the benefits are many. IMHO...  See also: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Administration/Configuring-a-CVS-Server/

Comment: @paulsm4:  I don't usually respond to the anti-TFS arguments.  But suggesting CVS?  In 2012?

Comment: Do you already have a TFS server that you are trying to share? Do you want your friend to collaborate on the source code or just get build drops from your server?  Also, consider using [Microsoft's hosted TFS service](http://tfspreview.com/) (currently free) to avoid dealing with the infrastructure yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS requires a dedicated server to use, it's not something you can (should) add to a production webserver, and it's a lot more involved than creating a folder for it to live in.

If you really need it to live on your webhost then look into something like GIT which I believe you may be able to do (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619/how-to-setup-git-bare-http-available-repository-on-iis-machine) - note i have no experience with this.

If you actually want TFS, then I recommend going with the TFSPreview.com and get Microsoft to host it for you.  Advantages over git being you have an integrated work item respository and build server, if you want those features with Git you'd need to look into another piece of software (cruise control.net etc) which would also won't live happily on a webserver either so you'd need to get a server or online service anyway.